# Problema con ReflectionException PHP 8.2.7 10.37.3 Function () does not exist En laravel

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

Hola buena ando con un problema que estoy intentando hacer el chat de un video de youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xAUl1qK0w4&list=PLIMuuuqKtStp5BOdU3d1mTE8Xd1pgrH0J&index=14

Y el codigo es este

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Chat;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }






    public function show(Chat $chat)
    {

        abort_unless($chat->users->contains(auth()->id()), 403);

        return view('chat', [
            'chat' => $chat
        ]);
    }

    public function chat_with(User $user)

    {
        $user_a = auth()->user();
        $user_b = $user;


        /* Busca la sala donde esta el user_a */
        $chat = $user_a->chats()->wherehas('users', function ($q) use ($user_b) {
            $q->where('chat_user.user_id', $user_b->id);
        })->first();

        if (!$chat) {
            $chat = \App\Models\Chat::create([]);

            $chat->users()->sync([$user_a->id, $user_b->id]);
        }

        return redirect()->route('chat.show', $chat);
    }




}
```

Intento acceder a la route esta

Route::get('chat/with/{user}', [ChatController::class, 'chat_with'])->name('chat.with');

Pero aparte estos son mis modelos que tengo para llamar al chats()

Modelo Chat.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



class Chat extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    public function users()

    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function mensajes()
    {

        return $this ->hasMany('App\Models\Mensaje');
    }
}
```

Y este el que tengo en User

```
 public function chats()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Chat::class, 'chat_user', 'user_id', 'chat_id');
    }
```

Pero nada me da error cambiando el codigo por este

```
public function chat_with(User $user)
    {
        $user_a = auth()->user();
        $user_b = $user;

        $chats = $user_a->chats;

        // Buscar la sala donde está el user_a
        $chat = $chats->whereIn('users.id', [$user_b->id])->first();

        if (!$chat) {
            // Si no se encuentra, crear un nuevo chat
            $chat = \App\Models\Chat::create([]);

            // Sincronizar usuarios en el nuevo chat
            $chat->users()->sync([$user_a->id, $user_b->id]);
        }

        return redirect()->route('chat.show', $chat);
    }
```

Que con este no me marca error del $chats.

y al tio del video le funciona sin problema. No entiendo la razon